# How to count one cell value depending upon the occurrence of specific value in another cell range

Tags: excel

I am working on an attendance sheet in Excel 2010. I need to count total no of attendance of a student in terms of his/her category. 
For example, I have 4 student categories:
CAT1
CAT2
CAT3 
CAT4

Please note that the sheet is not shorted on category, so their occurrence is random. Now I have 30-31 cells adjacent to these categories for attendance. These cells have values either a "P" or an "A". 
Now I have to count total no of attendance in each category after the end of the month.
Please help !

EDIT: Kindly see the image:
[image: The structure of the sheet]

EDIT:   @Rosenheimer, As you can see in the image I uploaded, my cell range for attendance is not contiguous. Is there any way to refer to multiple cell ranges in SUMPRODUCT? Right now, I am using 1 SUMPRODUCT for each range and adding them which is very lengthy:
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!E6:Sheet1!AI14=Sheet1!A65)*(Sheet1!D6:Sheet1!D14=Sheet1!A69)*(Sheet1!C6:Sheet1!C14=Sheet1!A67))+SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!E18:Sheet1!AI26=Sheet1!A65)*(Sheet1!D18:Sheet1!D26=Sheet1!A69)*(Sheet1!C18:Sheet1!C26=Sheet1!A67))+SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!E30:Sheet1!AI37=Sheet1!A65)*(Sheet1!D30:Sheet1!D37=Sheet1!A69)*(Sheet1!C30:Sheet1!C37=Sheet1!A67))+SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!E41:Sheet1!AI45=Sheet1!A65)*(Sheet1!D41:Sheet1!D45=Sheet1!A69)*(Sheet1!C41:Sheet1!C45=Sheet1!A67))+SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!E49:Sheet1!AI62=Sheet1!A65)*(Sheet1!D49:Sheet1!D62=Sheet1!A69)*(Sheet1!C49:Sheet1!C62=Sheet1!A67))

Thank you !

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with a conditional sum:
Please note that it is called `SUMPRODUCT` in English Excel applications (function names are translated for Microsoft Excel).
[image]

The evaluation `A$2:A$7=D2` is either true or false, which will be interpreted as 0 (false) or 1 (true) for the multiplication with the literal `1`.

Now you can add further statements to the evaluation, for example you might extend it to `(A$2:A$7=D2)*(C$2:C$7="P")*(F$2:F$7>=DATE(2015,07,01))*(F$2:F$7<DATE(2015,08,01))` to only count students that are marked with P in July.

Edit:
Since you're effectively using a matrix and not just a list, you need to use a sligthly different variation, but it can still be done with `SUMPRODUCT`, look at this example:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I am not able to get the required result. Kindly see the image I just uploaded. I am working on this structure.

Comment: I just uploaded the solution for your structure. If your "Sunday" columns are single cells instead of a big joined cell, you should probably make it into a joined cell if you want to count on "A"'s, otherwise you'de have to build a date check in the function (which would make the formula quite a bit longer).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the occurrence of different cells that meet a specific criteria then use the function `"COUNTIF"`. But if you want to count cells that fulfill multiple criteria then use the function `"COUNTIFS"`

Comment: COUNTIFS is not working for me. Kindly see the image I just uploaded for better understanding of the sheet